# How to compare value of two boxed variables?

Tags: c#, boxing

Consider the following code:

```
object a1 = (int) 2;
object a2 = (long) 2;
a1 == a2 //False
```

I know that boxing happens here and `==` operator now compares equality of two references (`a1` and `a2`).

The problem here is that I want to compare the values `a1` and `a2` refer to. How can I do that?

**PS:** In my real life problem I don't know the exact types of `a1` and `a2`. They can be any reference type of value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `int` and a `long` are never equal, so ...

The overload of `==` to use is fixed at compile-time. Except if you say:

```
(dynamic)a1 == (dynamic)a2
```

in which case the binding (which overload?) happens at run-time, which should actually work in your example, since there exists an overload:

```
bool operator ==(long, long)
```

built-in in C#.

**Warning:** Binding can fail, and if you use `dynamic` you may run into an exception (run-time) because of that. Something like:

```
dynamic a1 = 2;
dynamic a2 = "two";
dynamic test = a1 == a2;  // Bang?
```

---

If you do not want `dynamic`, you could try with `Convert.ChangeType` if either comparand can have its type changed to match the type of the other one. Then you could call `Equals` which is `virtual` and will find the overridden implementation (like `int.Equals` or `long.Equals`, each overriding `object.Equals`).

Comment: So why `(int)2 == (long)2` returns true? And what happens If I don't develop in c# 4?

Comment: @alisabzevari, that's because the `==` operator is overloaded for `long`, so an implicit conversion is made from `int` to `long`

Comment: So why they didn't use implicit conversion in `int.Equals` and `long.Equals`? I think that can solve the problem.

Comment: @alisabzevari One reason for not doing that I can think of, is that `a1.Equals(a2)` should be equivalent to `a2.Equals(a1)` in most cases.

Comment: @alisabzevari Note, that because of overloads, and implicit conversions, if you use the actual types at compile-time, that is `int a1 = 2; long a2 = 2L;`, then certainly `a1.Equals(a2) != a2.Equals(a1)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen What is the solution for prior .net 4?

Comment: @alisabzevari You could not use `dynamic` if the .NET version was less than 4.0, or if the C# compiler was earlier than version 4. You would have to manually check if `var convertible1 = a1 as IConvertible;` was non-null, and if so try one of the methods it has, for example converting everything into `long`. This is more or less equivalent to `Convert.ChangeType` which I mentioned (it could give boxed `long` on which you could use `Equals` to another (boxed) `long`). How many different types of `2` do you need to be equal?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to unbox the variables by casting them to their underying type.

If for some reason you don't know the types, the simplest way to achieve this if you don't know the types of the underlying variables is to use the dynamic language features in C#.

```
object a1 = (int) 2;
object a2 = (long) 2;
a1 == a2 // False
(dynamic) a1 == (dynamic) a2 // True
```

Mind that this is slow and what you are tring to achieve can usually be done better with explicit casts.